# Which layout will make a similar dropdown list like standard listbox dropdown list?

Tags: android

I found and tried this code from developer.android.com to create a spinner populated from a string-array resource :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> produits_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.produits_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
produits_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

I don't like the design of the dropdown list after clicking the arrow of the spinner :

[image]

I want a dropdown list like standard listbox's dropdown list which is also situated below the spinner. So what is the best layout for that instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may implement your own structure easily with TextView and ListView

Comment: How to set its coordinate relatively to the spinner's coordinates ?

Comment: Use RelativeLayout and use "Below", "AlignLeft" and it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AlertDialog.Builder`for showing list.

```
    AlertDialog dialog;
    CharSequence[] items = {"A", "B", "C"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTitle("List")
    .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if(item==0){

            }
            else if(item==1){

            }
            else if(item==2){

            }   
        }

    });
   dialog=builder.create();
   dialog.show();
```